# node.js axios Turkish character converter problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

The result: "Öncü"
I want it like this: "Öncü"

I fixed my problem by writing custom function like this:

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow changed the text.
The result: "& #214;nc& #252;"

Comment: Do not post images of code!

Comment: I couldn't share the codes, I don't know why. So I shared the image of code.